# Loading Beans based on hostname

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I am writing services in Spring boot that get their configurations from Spring cloud. These services are multi-tenant and the tenant is based on the host name.

what I have now is

```
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyServiceFactory factory) {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping("some/path/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<SomeEntity> getSomeEntity(@RequestHeader header, @PathVariable id) {
        return factory.getMyService(header).handle(id);
    }
}
```

where MyServiceFactory looks something like...

```
public class MyServiceFactory {
    private final HashMap<String, MyService> serviceRegistry = new HashMap<>();
    public MyService getMyService(String key) {
        return serviceRegistry.get(key);
    }

    MyServiceFactory withService(String key, MyService service) {
        this.serviceRegistry.put(key, service);
        return this;
    }

}
```

then in a configuration file

```
@Configuration
public ServiceFactoryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyServiceFactory getMyServiceFactory() {
        return new MyServiceFactory()
            .withService("client1", new MyService1())
            .withService("client2", new MyService2());
    }
}
```

While what I have now works, I don't like that I need to create a factory for every dependency my controller may have. I'd like to have my code look something like this...

```
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyService service) {
    ...
    }

    @RequestMapping("some/path/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<SomeEntity> getSomeEntity(@PathVariable id) {
        return service.handle(id);
    }
}
```

with a configuration file like

```
@Configuration
public class MyServiceConfiguration() {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("Client1")
    public MyService getMyService1() {
        return new MyService1();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("Client2")
    public MyService getMyService2() {
        return new MyService2();
    }
}
```

I can get the code that I want to write if I use a profile at application start up. But I want to have lots of different DNS records pointing to the same (pool of) instance(s) and have an instance be able to handle requests for different clients. I want to be able to swap out profiles on a per request basis.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Don't... Create a proxy for `MyService` and based on the tenant use the correct one. We used that approach to switch datasources on the fly. I blogged about it [here](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/) and the code is [here](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-utils). (I'm working on pulling it out into it's own project). What it provides is the ability to switch any bean at runtime with the one you want/need or a default one.

Comment: Why not use spring profiles, one for each host and then pass the hostname on startup as the profile name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring profiles would not help here, you would need one application context per client, and that seems not what you want.

Instead you could use scoped beans.
Create your client dependent beans with scope 'client' :

```
@Bean
@Scope(value="client",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@Primary
MyService myService(){
    //does not really matter, which instance you create here
    //the scope will create the real instance
    //may be you can even return null, did not try that.
    return new MyServiceDummy();
}
```

There will be at least 3 beans of type MyService : the scoped one, and one for each client. The annotation @Primary tells spring to always use the scoped bean for injection.

Create a scope  :

```
public class ClientScope implements Scope {
   @Autowired
   BeanFactory beanFactory;

   Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory){
       //we do not use the objectFactory here, instead the beanFactory           
       //you somehow have to know which client is the current
       //from the config, current request, session,  or ThreadLocal..
       String client=findCurrentClient(..);
       //client now is something like 'Client1'

      //check if your cache (HashMap) contains an instance with
      //BeanName = name for the client, if true, return that
       ..  
      //if not, create a new instance of the bean with the given name 
      //for the current client. Easiest way using a naming convention 
        String clientBeanName=client+'.'+name;
        Object clientBean=BeanFactory.getBean(clientBeanName);
      //put in cache ...
        return clientBean;  
   };
}
```

And your client specific beans are configured like this :

```
@Bean('Client1.myService')
public MyService getMyService1() {
    return new MyService1();
}

@Bean('Client2.myService')
public MyService getMyService2() {
    return new MyService2();
}
```

Did not test it but used it in my projects. Should work.

[tutorial spring custom scope](http://www.techsach.com/2014/11/spring-custom-scope.html)